# Drupal Views: filtering on a cck field?

Tags: drupal-6

Content type Events has intro, body and an "event date" field (using Date module). In the Page View I'd like to filter nodes so that only items with an "event date" in the future appear.

Problem is, when I try to add a filter field, this "event date" does not appear in the list.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Seems simple enough yet I dont see this field, even after clearing all caches etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the `Date: Date (node)` filter type. When you select it, the next screen will prompt for which CCK fields to filter by. That's where you'll need to select the `event date` field.

Comment: +1 - What is it with all these 'accept but no upvote' lately?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer finally , the perfect one and the right one

for views filter content date

extra one module views_attach  that enable your content and profile to add with views and allow more solution for you

Answer (score 0):

filter [+] then

from the group selection , select date

then date [node]

then, u show the list of criteria  follow steps

then update and save ...

Answer (score 0):

No this is wrong one

filter - > group -> content ->   here field which create in content type cck date , must be shown.....